# Java Swing Draw Applet

Tags: java, swing

I'm doing an assignment and I've hit a brick wall and could really use some direction. The program launches a Java GUI applet (I have this working) and within that applet, you can select between a few options, such as, the shape type (Oval or Rectangle), Fill Type (Solid or Hollow) and Color (a few color options).

There's a single Draw button in the app and this draw button should draw an image based on the selections made above.

For shape type, I'm looking at the selection with an "if" statement and statically setting the drawing to be an oval or rectangle based on what's selected.

```
                for (String value : shapeType) {
                    if (value.equals("Rectangle")) {
                        shapeDimensions = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200);
                    } else {
                        shapeDimensions = new Rectangle(40, 30, 100, 125);
                    }
                }
```

The same applies for Color, if the selection is Red then I set the "color" variable to `color = new Color(255, 0, 0)`.

The problem I'm having is with the Fill Type (Solid or Hollow)? I'm not sure what to do with this. I've put all of my code in below for reference. As you will see, I have a custom `Shape` abstract Class and constructor that I should be passing this information too. I then have methods such as `setColor` and `getSolid` along with two sub-classes called Rectangle and Oval where depending on my selection of the shape type (Oval or Rectangle), I should draw one of those shapes.

I have no idea what to do with Fill Type or how to pass that to something. I'm also not sure I'm using the correct parameter types under my `Shape` class. I'm also not sure I should be doing the calculations to determine the color and Shape Type the way I am under my draw button actionListener. Any and all help would be much appreciated!

```
package PRJ3;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class PRJ3 extends JFrame {
    public PRJ3() {
    }

    abstract static class Shape extends Rectangle {
        private static Color shapeColor;
        private static Shape shape;
        private static Rectangle shapeType;

        Shape(Rectangle shapeType, Color shapeColor, Shape shapeFill) {
            Shape.shapeType = shapeType;
            Shape.shapeColor = shapeColor;
            Shape.shape = shapeFill;
        } // end Shape constructor

        public void setColor(Color shapeColor) {
            /** should accept the graphics object as a parameter and set the color for the next
             *  draw operation to the color of the current shape.
             */
            Shape.shapeColor = shapeColor;
        }

        public Shape getSolid() {
            return shape;
        }

        static int getNoOfShapes() {
            return 1;
        }

        abstract void draw (Graphics graphicObject);

        static class Oval extends Shape {
        Dimension objectDimension;
        Rectangle graphicObject;
        Color shapeColor;
        Shape shapeFill;

        Oval(Rectangle graphicObject, Color shapeColor, Shape shapeFill) {
            super(graphicObject, shapeColor, shapeFill);
        }

            @Override
            void draw(Graphics graphicObject) {

            }

        } // end over Oval subClass

        static class Rectangular extends Shape {

        Rectangular(Rectangle graphicObject, Color shapeColor, Shape shapeFill) {
            super(graphicObject, shapeColor, shapeFill);
        }

        @Override
        void draw(Graphics graphicObject) {
            Drawing drawRectangle = new Drawing();
        }

    } // end of Rectangle subClass

        static class Drawing extends JPanel {
            private Shape shape;

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawString("Shapes: " + Shape.getNoOfShapes(), 10, 20);
                /** Shape isn't initialized when this is called the first time */
                if (shape != null) {
                    shape.draw(g);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(200, 200);
            }

            public void drawShape() throws OutsideBounds {
                // check provided size vs preferred size
                if (shape.getWidth() > this.getPreferredSize().getWidth() || shape.getHeight() > this.getPreferredSize().getHeight()) {
                    throw new OutsideBounds();
                } else {
                    this.shape = shape;
                    repaint();
                }

            } // end drawShape

        } // end of Drawing subClass

        static class OutsideBounds extends Throwable {
}

    } // end of Shape parent class

    static public void main(String[] args) {

        JPanel contentPane;
        JTextField tfWidth;
        JTextField tfHeight;
        JTextField tfxCoordinate;
        JTextField tfyCoordinate;
        JComboBox cbxShapeType;
        JLabel lblShapeType;
        JPanel panelShapeDrawing;
        JLabel lblFillType;
        JComboBox cbxFillType;
        JLabel lblColor;
        JComboBox cbxColor;
        JLabel lblWidth;
        JLabel lblHeight;
        JLabel lblxCoordinate;
        JLabel lblyCoordinate;
        JButton btnDraw;
        final String[] shapeType = new String[1];
        final String[] shapeColor = new String[1];
        final String[] shapeFill = new String[1];

        JFrame Frame = new JFrame("Geometric Drawing");
        Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Frame.setBounds(100, 100, 601, 330);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        Frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[] {20, 106, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[] {30, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 19, 30, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

        lblShapeType = new JLabel("Shape Type");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblShapeType = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblShapeType.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_lblShapeType.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_lblShapeType.gridx = 1;
        gbc_lblShapeType.gridy = 1;
        contentPane.add(lblShapeType, gbc_lblShapeType);

        String[] shapeTypes = {"" ,"Oval", "Rectangle"};
        cbxShapeType = new JComboBox(shapeTypes);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_cbxShapeType = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_cbxShapeType.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_cbxShapeType.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_cbxShapeType.gridx = 2;
        gbc_cbxShapeType.gridy = 1;
        contentPane.add(cbxShapeType, gbc_cbxShapeType);

        panelShapeDrawing = new JPanel();
        panelShapeDrawing.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        String title = "Shape Drawing";
        Border border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title);
        panelShapeDrawing.setBorder(border);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_panelShapeDrawing = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_panelShapeDrawing.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_panelShapeDrawing.gridwidth = 10;
        gbc_panelShapeDrawing.gridheight = 8;
        gbc_panelShapeDrawing.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_panelShapeDrawing.gridx = 3;
        gbc_panelShapeDrawing.gridy = 1;
        contentPane.add(panelShapeDrawing, gbc_panelShapeDrawing);

        lblFillType = new JLabel("Fill Type");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblFillType = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblFillType.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_lblFillType.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_lblFillType.gridx = 1;
        gbc_lblFillType.gridy = 2;
        contentPane.add(lblFillType, gbc_lblFillType);

        String[] fillTypes = {"", "Solid", "Hollow"};
        cbxFillType = new JComboBox(fillTypes);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_cbxFillType = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_cbxFillType.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_cbxFillType.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_cbxFillType.gridx = 2;
        gbc_cbxFillType.gridy = 2;
        contentPane.add(cbxFillType, gbc_cbxFillType);

        lblColor = new JLabel("Color");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblColor = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblColor.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_lblColor.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_lblColor.gridx = 1;
        gbc_lblColor.gridy = 3;
        contentPane.add(lblColor, gbc_lblColor);

        String[] supportedColors = {"", "Red", "Black", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Magenta"};
        cbxColor = new JComboBox(supportedColors);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_cbxColor = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_cbxColor.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_cbxColor.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_cbxColor.gridx = 2;
        gbc_cbxColor.gridy = 3;
        contentPane.add(cbxColor, gbc_cbxColor);

        lblWidth = new JLabel("Width");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblWidth = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblWidth.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_lblWidth.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_lblWidth.gridx = 1;
        gbc_lblWidth.gridy = 4;
        contentPane.add(lblWidth, gbc_lblWidth);

        tfWidth = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_tfWidth = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_tfWidth.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_tfWidth.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_tfWidth.gridx = 2;
        gbc_tfWidth.gridy = 4;
        contentPane.add(tfWidth, gbc_tfWidth);
        tfWidth.setColumns(10);

        lblHeight = new JLabel("Height");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblHeight = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblHeight.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_lblHeight.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_lblHeight.gridx = 1;
        gbc_lblHeight.gridy = 5;
        contentPane.add(lblHeight, gbc_lblHeight);

        tfHeight = new JTextField();
        tfHeight.setColumns(10);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_tfHeight = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_tfHeight.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_tfHeight.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_tfHeight.gridx = 2;
        gbc_tfHeight.gridy = 5;
        contentPane.add(tfHeight, gbc_tfHeight);

        lblxCoordinate = new JLabel("x coordinate");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblxCoordinate = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblxCoordinate.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_lblxCoordinate.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_lblxCoordinate.gridx = 1;
        gbc_lblxCoordinate.gridy = 6;
        contentPane.add(lblxCoordinate, gbc_lblxCoordinate);

        tfxCoordinate = new JTextField();
        tfxCoordinate.setColumns(10);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_tfxCoordinate = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_tfxCoordinate.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_tfxCoordinate.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_tfxCoordinate.gridx = 2;
        gbc_tfxCoordinate.gridy = 6;
        contentPane.add(tfxCoordinate, gbc_tfxCoordinate);

        lblyCoordinate = new JLabel("y coordinate");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblyCoordinate = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblyCoordinate.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_lblyCoordinate.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_lblyCoordinate.gridx = 1;
        gbc_lblyCoordinate.gridy = 7;
        contentPane.add(lblyCoordinate, gbc_lblyCoordinate);

        tfyCoordinate = new JTextField();
        tfyCoordinate.setColumns(10);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_tfyCoordinate = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_tfyCoordinate.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_tfyCoordinate.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_tfyCoordinate.gridx = 2;
        gbc_tfyCoordinate.gridy = 7;
        contentPane.add(tfyCoordinate, gbc_tfyCoordinate);

        btnDraw = new JButton("Draw");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_btnDraw = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btnDraw.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_btnDraw.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        gbc_btnDraw.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_btnDraw.gridx = 2;
        gbc_btnDraw.gridy = 8;
        contentPane.add(btnDraw, gbc_btnDraw);

        btnDraw.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                Shape.Drawing customShape = new Shape.Drawing();
                shapeType[0] = (String) cbxShapeType.getSelectedItem();
                shapeFill[0] = (String) cbxFillType.getSelectedItem();
                shapeColor[0] = (String) cbxColor.getSelectedItem();
                Rectangle shapeDimensions = null;
                Color color = null;
                Shape shape = null;


                for (String value : shapeType) {
                    if (value.equals("Rectangle")) {
                        shapeDimensions = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200);
                    } else {
                        shapeDimensions = new Rectangle(40, 30, 100, 125);
                    }
                }

                for (String value : shapeFill) {
                    if (value.equals("Fill")) {
                        Shape fill = new Rectangle2D()
                    }
                }

                for (String s : shapeColor) {
                    if (s.equals("Red")) {
                        color = new Color(255, 0, 0);
                    } else if (s == "Black") {
                        color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
                    } else if (s == "Orange") {
                        color = new Color(255, 102, 0);
                    } else if (s == "Yellow") {
                        color = new Color(255, 255, 0);
                    } else if (s == "Green") {
                        color = new Color(0, 204, 0);
                    } else if (s == "Blue") {
                        color = new Color(0, 0, 255);
                    } else if (s == "Magenta") {
                        color = new Color(255, 0, 255);
                    }
                }

                Color finalColor = color;
                Shape test = new Shape(shapeDimensions, finalColor, shape) {
                    @Override
                    void draw(Graphics graphicObject) {
                    }
                };
                test.setColor(color);
            }
        });

        panelShapeDrawing.setVisible(true);
        contentPane.setVisible(true);
        Frame.setVisible(true);

    } // end main

} // end PRJ3
```

Comment: `Graphics2D` has both a `draw(Shape)` & a [**`fill(Shape)`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#fill(java.awt.Shape)) method. If that does not answer your question, please explain further.

Comment: I did see that but I'm not sure how I would use that based on my current layout. If I use the draw() and fill() methods and pass "Shape", where do I get Shape from? Should that be my ```shapeDimensions``` variable (from Shape Type)? Because that's a Rectangle type and the draw() and fill() methods are looking for a Graphics parameter. I have a method called ```paintComponent``` where I could pass my Shape but again, that's looking for a Graphics parameter.

Comment: *where do I get Shape from?* - that is a parameter of your "Draw" class. When you use a JLabel, you have methods like setText, setForeground, setBackground, setFont etc. So for your "Draw" class you need methods like setShape, setColor, Then in the paintComponent() method you use the properties from those methods to do the painting. Or, you can check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). It demonstrates how you can paint multiple coloured rectangles on the same panel.

Comment: I assume you're referring to my "Drawing" class where I've extended JPanel. I don't have a class called "Draw" where I'm extending JLabel. Also, the classes and methods you see here are the ones that we were advised to use, and nothing more. Also, can you explain how I would use the Rectangle and Oval sub-classes. There is an overridden draw method in those classes but should I do the drawing there or in the "Drawing" class? All very confusing and I suck with Swing! Thanks for your help thus far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also, the classes and methods you see here are the ones that we were advised to use,

Well, I don't know what has been given to you and what you have written yourself, but what I see above is confusing.

To me it looks like you have 3 properties to control the painting:

1. Rectangle, which contains the location and size of the shape to be painted.
2. Color
3. Filled, which should be a Boolean property to control if the shaped should be painted filled or with an outline only.

So your `Shape` class should not extend Rectangle. It should just be a class with the above 3 properties and your `draw(Graphics g)` method.

Note the JDK has a `Shape` class so I don't like to use the same name as it causes confusion.

So I would do something like:

```
public abstract class DrawableShape
{
    protected Rectangle rectangle;
    protected Color color;
    protected boolean filled;

    public DrawableShape(Rectangle rectangle, Color color, boolean filled)
    {
        this.rectangle = rectangle;
        this.color = color;
        this.filled = filled;
    }

    abstract void draw(Graphics g);
}
```

Now you need to implement the painting code for your Rectangle and Oval objects. Something like:

```
public class DrawableRectangle extends DrawableShape
{
    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor( color );

        if (filled)
            g.fillRect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, rectangle.width, rectangle.height);
        else
            g.drawRect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, rectangle.width, rectangle.height);
    }
}
```

Now in your `DrawingPanel` you need a method like:

```
public void setDrawableShape(DrawableShape drawableShape)
{
    this.drawableShape = drawableShape;
    repaint();
}
```

Ant the painting code need to paint this shape:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent( g );
    drawableShape.draw();
}
```

Then in the ActionListener you code you need to add the DrawableShape to your Drawing class:

```
DrawableShape drawableShape = null;

if (value.equals("Rectangle"))
    drawableShape = new DrawableRectangle(….);
else
    drawableShape = new DrawableOval(...);

drawing.setDrawableShape( drawableShape );
```

The above structure will allow you to paint only a single shape on your Drawing panel. If you need multiple shapes, then you need to modify your Drawing class. The link I provided you above on "Custom Painting Approaches" shows how to do this.

Comment: Where do a get a Graphics object to pass as a parameter to my "paintComponent" method? The "drawableShape" variable is of type "DrawableShape" so my paintComponent method won't accept it.

Comment: The painting subsystem is responsible for painting Swing components. When Swing determines a component need to be painted it creates the Graphics object and invokes the painting methods. I did not suggest you pass DrawableShape to the paintComponent() method. Look at my code suggestions again. Think about how a JLabel is painted. You use methods like setText(…), setForeground(…), setIcon(…) to set the properties of the label. In your case your property is the DrawableShape object.

Comment: Have you looked at the link I provided you yet?? It show you how to use Objects that contain information about the object to be painted. Also, read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for a more detail explanation on how painting works.

Comment: *I can only get the program to draw the shape once.* - I have already addressed this issue: 1) in my original comment to your question before I provided the more detailed answer 2) in my original answer and finally 3) in my last comment to this answer. So my thoughts are that you need to read all the suggestions given and follow all the links provided.

Comment: I got it working using the following line: 
panelShapeDrawing.removeAll(). This is at the top of my btnDraw actionListener method. Everyday I click the button, it clears the panel now and then draws a new image.

Comment: My above comment was assuming you wanted to display multiple shapes at the same time on the frame. So that reading should be done at a later time to learn that concept. *panelShapeDrawing.removeAll().* That is not the proper solution. the DrawingPanel should only be created once, when you create all the other Swing components. You then simply invoke the setDrawableShape(…) method to change the shape. This is exactly how all other Swing components work. That is when you want to change the text on a JLabel you don't create a new JLabel. Instead you invoked setText(…) on the existing label.

Comment: So I agree with you regarding the call to setDrawableShape and that should change the shape in the panel but it doesn't. It didn't change until I removed what was already in the panel.

Comment: Then there is still something wrong with your code. The only reason you would need the removeAll() statement is if you are adding multiple components to the same panel! Did you add the repaint() to the setDrawableImage() method? Did you debug the paintComponent() method to make sure the code is invoked?

Comment: Correct, the repaint method is within my setDrawableShape method.

            public void setDrawableShape(DrawableShape drawableShape) throws OutsideBounds {
                if (drawableShape.rectangle.getWidth() > this.getPreferredSize().getWidth() || drawableShape.rectangle.getHeight() > this.getPreferredSize().getHeight()) {
                    throw new OutsideBounds();
                } else {
                    this.drawableShape = drawableShape;
                    repaint();
                }
            }. I also did debug and setDrawableShape is called but aren't rendered